# Does StringBuilder creates a new String in every operation?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

How many objects were created with this code? - I know the 3 String literals are in the String Constant Pool and the StringBuilder object is at the heap but does it creates a new String in the pool when i call reverse(), insert() or append() ?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
sb.append("def").reverse().insert(3, "---");
System.out.println( sb );
```

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/StringBuilder.java I found this :) can help you if you want to know more about it

Comment: That was very helpful! Now i see how it internally works

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`StringBuilder` will only create a new string when `toString()` is called on it. Until then, it keeps an `char[]` array of all the elements added to it.

Any operation you perform, like `insert` or `reverse` is performed on that array.

Comment: what abt intern method ?

Comment: It will insert on the char[] array. Very efficient

Comment: When we call `append(String str)`, wont the jvm create the another string object ?

Comment: Good Answer. Thanks. (Studying for Java 6 Certification)

Comment: @GabrielBB @alancnet, Overall there would be 4 objects or only 1 ? I think when we call `append(String str)`, first `str` has to be created correct?

Comment: 4 Objects without counting the internal Char[] array ("I know the 3 String literals are in the String Constant Pool and the StringBuilder object is at the heap")

Answer (score 3):

Strings created: `"abc", "def", "---"`

StringBuilders created: `sb`

`sb.append("def").reverse().insert(3, "---")` are not creating new objects, just editing the `StringBuilder's` internal buffer (that's why using StringBuilder is recomended for performances).

Comment: @alancnet reply object char[] parameter contradicts this reply

Comment: Actually there is one more string beside `"abc"`, `"def"`, `"---"`. `System.out.println` uses `String.valueOf` which invokes `toString()` on passed object and since we passed `sb` it invoked its `toString` method which created this additional instance.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, you're right :) If we want to be strict, maybe there are also some other internal `StringBuilder`'s objects that were created by the `StringBuilder`'s constructor.

Comment: I guess is the same for StringBuffer class

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abc");
sb.append("def").reverse().insert(3, "---");
System.out.println( sb );
```

Only 1 Object of StringBuilder will be created in the heap, no matter which ever method provided by the class is used like append,reverse etc.

The memory once allocated will not be changed whether you use `toString()` method to cast it into String.